# Can we kill the consolidate tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

Its not *too* bad, only 10 uses of it, and Its easy to eliminate. Its got no tag wiki, and as such it won't be missed if we drag it out somewhere and bury it. Its a classic metatag apparently used with excel questions and file management. So can we consolidate the [consolidate](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/consolidate) tag into the wastebin of history?

Comment: Just kill it please. And make it quick.

Comment: Ankles have been bitten, and tags killed dead.